# XPath: get list of parents but not any of their children

Tags: html, xpath

I am traversing a large HTML document and need to get the HTML of all elements with  a `class` containing `country`. However, I need to avoid including in the list all the children of these elements, which may have classes like `country-name` or `country-flag-image`.

So for instance, it might look like a list of elements of the following form:

```
<div class="country"><div class="country-body">Text</div></div>
```

And I would need to get the outer div elements but not also get the inner div elements, so this code will not work: `//*[contains(@class, "country")]`.

I need to use `contain` because the code needs to be flexible enough to work if the parent element class names vary a little bit or change (e.g. the outer div might change to `country-header`).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: So to be clear, your expected output is `<div class="country">`?

Comment: No, it's a list containing everything of the form <div class="country"><div class="country-body">Text</div></div>, but nothing of the form <div class="country-body">Text</div>.

Comment: To do that, you will need to use an XML parser (like lxml, if you're using Python).

Comment: Yep, I am. How can I do this in lxml?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import lxml.html as LH

xml="""
<div class="country"><div class="country-body">Text_1</div></div>
"""
doc = LH.fromstring(xml)
for elem in doc.iter():
    elem.text = ''
LH.tostring(doc)
```

Output:

```
'<div class="country"><div class="country-body"></div></div>\n'
```